# After Effects scripting - convert audio to keyframes?

Tags: javascript, audio, after-effects

How can you do "convert audio to keyframes" using scripting in after effects, manually you would right-click on the "sound" layer > keyframe assistant > convert audio to keyframes.

```
var myComp = app.project.activeItem;
var musicComp = myComp.layer("music");

var myEffect = musicComp.property("Effects").addProperty("High-Low Pass");
myEffect.property("Filter Options").setValue(1);
myEffect.property("Cutoff Frequency").setValue(50);

// then I want to do "convert audio to keyframes"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer provided by: Walter Soyka

```
app.executeCommand(app.findMenuCommandId("Convert Audio to Keyframes"));
```